# nginx restart fails, but reload works

Tags: nginx

I've added a new SSL certificate to my nginx server (I've done this many times before).
However, when I restart nginx, no sites are working.

When I run configtest, it says:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

If nginx is running and I run nginx reload, the sites and the new ssl certificate are working.

Only when Nginx restarts, I get following:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting nginx:
```

So nothing happens after the Starting nginx.
No message is written to the nginx error logs neither.

If I just use "start", often it does work.

What can I do to fix this and what could cause this?

Comment: Does `lsof -Pni` as root show anything for port 443? Are there any other previous connections showing (FIN_WAIT etc). I would think that nginx would have reuse-address socket option enabled by default (I've not yet used it); bit I've been surprised by this before.

Comment: What is there in log file? Paste the log in your question.

Comment: Nothing is written to the logs. The output of "lsof -Pni | grep 443" is empty, meaning there is no open connection or pending connection on that port.

Comment: Can you show your nginx config? Especially the part with the SSL parameters.

Comment: Can you confirm you ran that as root?

Comment: I wonder if the logs end up elsewhere. Can you grep through syslogs looking for nginx? Also, what permissions etc are on the log file? Does a stop/start (rather than a restart) exhibit the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you running restart? Via an init script or using service, or are you just running 'nginx restart'

To debug nginx the correct way is to add `debug` to the end of your error_log directive under HTTP. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html

But my money is on your PID file not being cleared when restart is called.

First kill nginx and start it up again in foreground mode by adding [`master_process off`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#master_process) or [`daemon off`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#daemon) to your nginx.conf file.

Run:

```
nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | tee ~/nginx.log
```

now in a different  terminal run:

```
nginx -s restart
```

And i hope you get lots of errors. 
You could also attach yourself to the main nginx process by running [`strace -fqp <pid>`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)
And try and see what its doing. (this I guess is a hail-mary approach but when you want to know exactly why the hell stuff isnt working, why not get all the information).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I changed the encoding of the ssl file itself and then it started working.

Note: I merged the ssl files together with the > command and that didn't work properly.
Downloaded the individual keys to my computer, put them together in 1 file manually and then uploaded and it started working.